# Why does WSAConnect socket Timeout on valid host

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, winapi

I'v tried to get back to an old C project and right from the start it doesn't work anymore.
Basically what it does is that it just create a socket (using WSAConnect) to a remote Host (which i can ping) but every time it try to connect to the remote host i get a timeout.

**Here is the code :**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024

void BindSock(char* rhost, int rport);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //FreeConsole(); // This is the way to make the cmd vanish
    char rhost[] = "g0blin.ovh"; // ip to connect to
    int rport = 1111;
    BindSock(rhost, rport);
    return 0;
}
void BindSock(char* rhost, int rport) {
    /*while (1) {*/
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }
    printf("[*] Winsock init ... \n");
    //init socket props
    SOCKET sock;
    sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 0, 0, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    printf("[*] Sock init ... \n");
    //Filling struc props
    struct sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, rhost, &(clientService.sin_addr));
    clientService.sin_port = htons(rport);

    printf("[*] attempting to connect \n");
    iResult = WSAConnect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("[!] connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(sock);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            printf("[!] closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    printf("[X] Sock Connected\n");
```

**What i tried so far :**

- I tried to ping the host and i can
- I changed the remote host and it doesn't work (i can also ping it)
- I tried disabling firewall and Anti-virus

**My guess** :

Since i have no error code other than Timeout i was wondering if some standards changed and that it would interfere with the way it's supposed to work.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Try using  LocalHost (  `127.0. 0.1` ) as `rhost`  for a quick test.

Comment: Does `InetPton` do name resolution or can it only handle numeric IP addresses in text form? (e.g. "127.0.0.1") Check the return value and the result in `clientService.sin_addr`

Comment: @ryyker I tried localhost and it didn't work either

Comment: @Bodo i'll check that right now

Comment: `LocalHost` ( `127.0. 0.1` ) and using `rport = 80` I was able to connect with no other changes. This suggests that your `IP`/`Port` values need to be looked at.    Web server ports are typically `80`, while SMTP servers use `25`.  Are you sure `1111` is correct for this `IP` address?

Comment: @ryyker Yeah i'm pretty sure 1111 is correct since it's the port i chose when i used netcat (nc -lvp 1111), but i'll try with the port 80, cheers

Comment: @ryyker it still doesnt work, i'll just install a VM and test it, my computer might be the problem and i don't know why

Comment: have you tried connecting to that port via another program? e.g. curl, telnet or a web browser? probably being blocked by a firewall somewhere

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just tried and i can connect to port 1111 using powershell, it's really weird

Comment: @Bodo "*Does `InetPton` do name resolution*" - no, it does not. Use `getaddrinfo()` for that. "*or can it only handle numeric IP addresses in text form*" - correct.

Comment: @Quentin_otd Try to initialize `rhost` with the text representation of the numeric IP address of your server instead of the name `"g0blin.ovh"` or use `"127.0.0.1"`  instead of `"localhost"`.

Comment: For localhost, have you checked the state of the port with `netstat -an`?

Answer (score 2):

`g0blin.ovh` is not a string representation of an IPv4 address, it is a hostname, so `InetPton()` will fail to parse it, but you are not checking for that condition, and thus you are passing an invalid `sockaddr_in` to `WSAConnect()`.

You need to use `getaddrinfo()` instead, which will parse IP address strings, AND perform hostname lookups, as needed.  It will also allow you to support IPv6 in addition to IPv4.  For example:

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 1024

void BindSock(const char* rhost, unsigned short rport);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //FreeConsole(); // This is the way to make the cmd vanish
    char rhost[] = "g0blin.ovh"; // ip to connect to
    unsigned short rport = 1111;
    BindSock(rhost, rport);
    return 0;
}

void BindSock(const char* rhost, unsigned short rport) {
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return;
    }
    printf("[*] Winsock init ... \n");

    //lookup host
    struct addrinfo hints = {0}, *result;
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;// use AF_UNSPEC instead to handle IPv4 + IPv6 together...
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    char szport[6] = {};
    sprintf(szport, "%hu", rport);

    iResult = getaddrinfo(rhost, szport, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        printf("getaddrinfo function failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
    printf("[*] host found ... \n");

    //init socket props
    SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    for(struct addrinfo *addr = result; addr != NULL; addr = addr->ai_next)
    {
        sock = WSASocketW(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol, 0, 0, 0);
        if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            continue;
        }
        printf("[*] Sock init ... \n");

        char ip[46] = {0};
        void *psin_addr;

        switch (addr->ai_family)
        {
            case AF_INET:
                psin_addr = &(((struct sockaddr_in*)addr->ai_addr)->sin_addr);
                break;

            case AF_INET6:
                psin_addr = &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)addr->ai_addr)->sin6_addr);
                break;
        }

        inet_ntop(addr->ai_family, psin_addr, ip, sizeof(ip));
        printf("[*] attempting to connect to %s:%hu\n", ip, rport);

        iResult = WSAConnect(sock, addr->ai_addr, addr->ai_addrlen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (iResult != SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("[X] Sock Connected\n");
            break;
        }

        printf("[!] connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(sock);
        sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    // use sock as needed ...

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but unfortunatly i changed a while a go to basic IP and it didn't work, if the code works for you i'll assume something is wrong with my PC